# IntelliJ IDEA is not correctly forming Android project hierarchy?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I posted this question on the [IntelliJ community forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/435429) but it seems as if they aren't very active so I'll just post it right here on S/O. 
I'm new to IntelliJ and I'm switching to use it from Eclipse which was really buggy and not useful to my needs. However, I'm attempting to build an Android project in IntelliJ Idea and it is only creating a .idea folder and the src directory without any inner files in them like it should. I've got the Android-SDK properly installed and I'm using JDK 1.7 and I'm even following the directions to properly start an Android project from the IntelliJ Wiki ([found here](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Simple_Android_application_from_scratch_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_10.5)) but it still leads me to no success. It seems as if I've got the Android Support plugin already installed with my program but then again I'm not really sure. Can I get some help please so I don't have to revert back to Eclipse again? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete Android SDK and install it again, then download at least one Platform. IDEA runs SDK tools to create Android project template, for some reason it's failing on your system.

Check if it works better with JDK 1.6.

[See the screencast](http://www.screenr.com/dWd8) that I've just recorded.

Comment: Thanks! I can't test this solution yet but I'll test it in the morning and report back with my results. :)